# Attempt to present UITabBarController whose view is not in the view hierarchy - Firebase, Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm working on the login system for an app, and when a user **registers**, I would like it to go straight "into" the app. Meaning, **not** back to the login screen, and then redirected "into" the app, or prompted to then login after registering. The desired outcome is working with the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //The disallowed character set is the inverse of the allowed characters
    disallowedUsernameCharacters = allowedUsernameCharacters.invertedSet

    //Set the delegates
    confirmPassTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.delegate = self

    //Observe authentication events, if the authentication is successful, perform the segue
    ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock { (authData) -> Void in
        if authData != nil {

            //Use standard defaults
            let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            //Store the uid
            prefs.setObject(authData.uid as String, forKey: "UID")

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.successfulSignUp, sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In which if the user registers, and is authenticated, it will perform the segue to the **UITabBarController** which contains 5 tabs/views for the app itself. This works fine, but I am given the **Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

From doing some research, this seems to be a fairly common warning that people get. However, I would like to fix it so that all portions of the app will behave as expected. I found that some people recommended putting the code portion:

```
//Observe authentication events, if the authentication is successful, perform the segue
ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock { (authData) -> Void in
            if authData != nil {

                //Use standard defaults
                let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                //Store the uid
                prefs.setObject(authData.uid as String, forKey: "UID")

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.successfulSignUp, sender: nil)
            }
}
```

Inside of the **viewWillAppear** method because of the current view potentially not being on the hierarchy at the time the segue is called, but I don't think that is the fix here, because it's not being called immediately, only on authentication events - also I don't want to put it here because my understanding is that this method is called frequently depending on events.

I also found that some people were executing it on a different thread with something along the lines of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.successfulSignUp, sender: nil)
})
```

But what I am thinking is that, the "register" view controller that is triggering the segue, is not the top most view controller and that's why the error is occurring. Also, I read that a solution is to embed a UINavigationController, if this is the solution...does anyone know any resources on how to do this? If there is a different solution, what would it be? Any help would be great! Cheers.

**EDIT:**

My Storyboard looks like this:
[image: storyboard]

The entry point is to the UITabBarController, and in the AppDelegate.swift I check to see if the user is logged in by checking a boolean value in the user defaults, if they aren't logged in, I change the rootController to the LoginViewController, in which the user can login, and it will segue to the UITabBarController, or they can register, and on successful registration, it will segue to the UITabBarController - it is here that I'm getting the warning

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier` has to be done on the main thread. Adding dispatch_async is correct.

Comment: I still receive the warning with dispatch_async

Answer (score 0):

I have not figured out why, and once I do I will update the answer, but to resolve this i put the line `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.LoginToFeed, sender: nil)`

into a seperate function

```
func callSegue() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.LoginToFeed, sender: nil)
}
```

and call the function from the block and the warning no longer appears